# Hold browser close or tab close action to show custom navigation pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace the browser alert pop up with custom navigation pop up when there are unsaved changed on the form or page for Browser Tab close and Browser close event. For that I need a way to hold the closing event until the user performs continue action on the custom pop up and then again on continue perform the closing part.Is there any way to achieve this compatible to all browsers?

Comment: For security reasons, that is completely impossible.

Comment: You can't stop them from leaving, but you can let them know that there unsaved changes using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: I am currently using  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        debugger;       
        if (isEventBind) {
            return alertMessage;
        }
    };
Which shows the browser alert,but I want to replace it with my custom pop up.I have done this for Browser back event using the  window.addEventListener("popstate", function (e) { some code });
Is their any other way some what same as above code?

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.

Full specification info is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload but relevant parts that you may want to consider are:

> When this event returns (or sets the returnValue property to) a value other than null or undefined, the user is prompted to confirm the page unload. In some browsers, the return value of the event is displayed in this dialog. Starting with Firefox 44, Chrome 51, Opera 38 and Safari 9.1, a generic string not under the control of the webpage will be shown instead of the returned string. For example, Firefox displays the string "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved." (See bug 588292), and Chrome displays the string "Do you want to leave this site? Changes you made may not be saved" (see Chrome Platform Status).

and also

> You can and should handle this event through window.addEventListener() and the beforeunload event.